# What are the differences in raster formats between Civil3D, QGIS, and ArcGIS?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff

Civil3D uses a .dem / .tif format which calls many files from other sources invalid. Esri products seem to have richer metadata for TIFF rasters and will add data to TIFF files on disk. QGIS uses GDAL but doesn't automatically add any metadata.

I have found how to add pyramids, for example, in QGIS, but when I ingest a raster TIFF that I have exported from CloudCompare, for example, the metadata is basically non-existent. I would like to be able to route CloudCompare raster exports into C3D ultimately.

What are some of the specifications that determine the way GeoTIFF is implemented in these different platforms?